# Exponents with Logs

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Could someone show work for why $e^{2\ln(x)}$ = $x^2$ ? I ran across this while solving an ODE but have completely forgotten the rules used here. I hate to ask it, but i'd rather ask it this once than go on in ignorance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$
a^{bc} = \Big(a^b\Big)^c = \Big(c^c\Big)^b
$$
$$
e^{2\ln x} =\Big(e^{\ln x}\Big)^2 = \Big(x\Big)^2.
$$

Answer (score 3):

$2\ln{x}=\ln{x^2}$ so $e^{2\ln x}=e^{\ln x^2}= x^2$

Comment: Please note that this identity is only true on the respective domains on either side of the equal sign. So technically, only for $x>0$